# ASP.NET emailing to multiple emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailaddress

I have this code here...

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("noreply@fakeemail.com", "IPC Orders");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("email1@fakeemail.com.com");
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);
        mail.To.Add("email2@fakeemail.com");
        mail.To.Add("email3@fakeemail.com");
```

Obviously this is not the full code, but when I try to send an email to multiple email address is doesnt send, if I comment out these two lines...

```
        mail.To.Add("email2@fakeemail.com");
        mail.To.Add("email3@fakeemail.com");
```

It works and will send it to the first email `MailAddress to = new MailAddress("email1@fakeemail.com.com");`

Whats wrong with my code

Comment: When you say it "doesn't send" what happens, do you get an exception?  Are the mails just not received?

Comment: email1@fakeemail.com.com ? is that an valid email? or an writing error?

Comment: Nothing is with this snippet of code. Either the email address are wrong, or you are encountering some exception. Did you try catching the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE  `AddressCollection` FOR ADDING MULTIPLE `TO` ADDRESSES
LIKE

mail.To = new AddressCollection( "email2@fakeemail.com, email3@fakeemail.com");

Comment: Welcome and at your service :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add add all your email addresses to a list, then just iterate over that list and send a mail at each element

```
List<string> emailAddress = new List<string>();
emailAddress.add("email1@em.com");
emailAddress.add("email2@em.com"); // ... etc


 foreach (string email in emailAddress)
 {
  MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, email);
  //+ more stuff
 }
```